# Blockchain.info has a service to list all the transactions which involve a bitcoin addresses generated using a given xpub.How does this work?

Tags: blockchain.info, bip32-hd-wallets

As per my understanding, there could be infinite addresses which can be generated, so how does this work?

Link: https://blockchain.info/xpub/xpub6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BIP-44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/1d371a58978fd2f313c9d162762de04d3b697bf5/bip-0044.mediawiki#Address_gap_limit) specifies a limit to how a wallet should look for public keys. The implementation should consider there's no address with funds beyond 20 addresses without funds.